# <select> option stay same after changing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added a theme select menu to my website, and I want to make the theme selection stay the same after you change the pages, as I added the selection menu to every page but it keeps resetting when changing pages, anyone could tell me how to do this? My code:

```
            <select onchange="javascript:changeColor(this);">
            <option selected disabled hidden>Theme</option>
            <optgroup label="Themes"></optgroup>
            <option value="white">Light</option>
            <option value="#222222">Dark</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
        </select>

<script>
function changeColor(el) {
    var theme = el.value;
    document.body.style.background = theme;
}
</script>
```

Comment: missing close tag of ``<optgroup>``

Comment: store the selected theme in 'session' or use `localstorage`.

Comment: Because page get changed so DOM set default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your desired color inside `localStorage`:

Playground: http://jsbin.com/cisicay/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```js
// On page load let's see if we stored any theme color
var theme = window.localStorage.theme;

// This function can be both triggered as Standalone 
// or on Select onchange event:

function changeColor(el) {
  // If it was triggered by our Select element store the new theme color
  if(el) theme = window.localStorage.theme = el.value;
  // Set the color
  if(theme) document.body.style.background = theme;
}

// Trigger theme change on page load
changeColor();
```

```html
<select onchange="changeColor(this);">
  <option disabled hidden>Theme</option>
  <optgroup label="Themes">
    <option value="#eee">Light</option>
    <option value="#222">Dark</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

#### Change the select value aswell

Here's another example that will change your `select` value aswell on page load and fallback to `#eee` (*light* variant)
<sub>(**note**: For this to work remove the default `selected` option attribute! And add an ID to your SELECT element)</sub>

Playground: http://jsbin.com/cisicay/3/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
function changeColor(el) {
  document.body.style.background = localStorage.theme = el ? el.value : localStorage.theme || "#eee";
  document.getElementById("theme").value = localStorage.theme
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<select id="theme" onchange="changeColor(this);">
  <option disabled hidden>Theme</option>
  <optgroup label="Themes">
    <option value="#eee">Light</option>
    <option value="#222">Dark</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Can I put all the <script> into the .js file or is something else used too?

Comment: Ok, worked!! The color stays the same, but the value of the <select> resets to the original one on refresh, any way to make it stay on the selected one?

Comment: @Omnitored yes! Use in line two: `yourSelectElement.value = theme;`

Comment: thank you!!! Exactly what I needed! Don't want to bother you more, as this is not in the question topic, but for some reason my <select> is placed behind the <nav> even when I put it inside it, is there any position or something similar atribute that places it infront of other elements? http://prntscr.com/cz25b5

Comment: Use CSS `position: fixed; top:0; z-index:999;` to stick it and float on top of all elements.

Comment: @Omnitored added another example with live `select` value change

Comment: just realized, after changing the page 2 times (for example home-contact-home the theme resets again to default.. :/

Comment: @Omnitored remove the `selected` attribute! (BOTH examples work perfectly well in jsBin so there's no reason it should not work on your side)

Comment: any chance you could join a chat with me and tell me what's wrong? I'll upload the website to a webhost
http://www.e-chat.co/room/168378

Answer (score 0):

Your script will run on every page load. You will need to store the selected value, and check it on page load.

```js
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
function changeColor(el) {
  var theme = el.value;
  document.body.style.background = theme;
  createCookie('siteTheme', theme, 365);
}
$(function() {
  var theme = readCookie('siteTheme');
  if( theme != '' && theme != 'undefined') {
    document.body.style.background = theme;
  }
});
```

```html
<select onchange="javascript:changeColor(this);">
  <option selected disabled hidden>Theme</option>
  <optgroup label="Themes">
    <option value="white">Light</option>
    <option value="#222222">Dark</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```